# Trace evaluation in inverse muon decay

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices, trace

Applying Casimir´s trick when averaging over the the initial and summating over the final spin states in the inverse muon decay yields (Griffiths, example 10.1) among others the following trace
$$
\text{p}_{1\lambda}\text{p}_{3\sigma}\text{tr}[\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma^5)(\gamma^{\lambda}+m_e)\gamma^{\nu}(1-\gamma^5)\gamma^{\sigma}]
$$
According to trace theorems this expression then simplifies to
$$
8[\text{p}_1^{\mu}\text{p}_3^{\nu}+\text{p}_1^{\nu}\text{p}_3^{\mu}-g^{\mu\nu}(\text{p}_1\cdot\text{p}_3)-i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}\text{p}_{1\lambda}\text{p}_{3\sigma}]
$$
Here is my question. Why is the index $\nu$ in the epsilon tensor in front of the $\lambda$. The trace theorems tell otherwise and no minus sign or whatsoever has been added to account for the odd permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just blew the sign!  Isolate the non-vanishing terms of your
$$
 p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}\text{Tr}[\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma^5)(\gamma^{\lambda}+m_e)\gamma^{\nu}(1-\gamma^5)\gamma^{\sigma}]
$$
linear in $\gamma^5$,
$$
2p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}\text{Tr}[\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\lambda} \gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\sigma}]\\ = 8i p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma} \epsilon^{\mu\lambda\nu\sigma}     = -8i p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda \sigma}.
$$

The  trace theorem 16 on your reference's p 239 is used, and *not* that of another text! It happens to coincide with trace identity 6 of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities), and amounts to the convention $\epsilon^{0123}=-1=-\epsilon_{0123}$, as commented in the text.

---

*Comment on P&S conventions alluded to in comment* :

P&S stick to a distinctly *different* convention, namely they make the *different choice* $\epsilon ^{0123}=1$, instead, as is evident from their (3.68),
$$
\gamma^5=i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3= -i\epsilon^{0123}\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3= i\epsilon^{0123}\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3, \\
\leadsto \epsilon^{0123}=1,
$$
so all their $\epsilon$s are minus those of WP and Griffiths.

Comment: Peskin and Schroeder states tr[$\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{5}$]=$-4i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$. Why does your trace linear in $\gamma^5$ then yield a positive sign? Via cyclic permutation they should be the same, right?

Comment: I amended my answer to reflect the identity your text sends you to. It does not send you to another one, P&S, with dramatically different (and nonstandard) conventions for  the Levi-Civita ε ; it should be evident to you from P&S (3.68) that they have chosen the tensor to be 1 for *contravariant*  0123... Ugh! Do they comment cautionarily on that?

Comment: Not as far as I have seen. I just noticed that they have seemingly used the same convention as you in worked examples later on.

Comment: It's quite possible they have collated several results from several sources, but that's definitely a different question. Griffiths does due diligence, and I hope you have checked the WP statements which are correct.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh sorry. I looked for something like it in the past but couldn´t find it until now.